# WCF Data Services: An error occurred while processing this request

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I set breakpoints everywhere and single-stepped through all my code, but could not find the source of the error. I saw no point in Googling for such a non-specific error..
I am getting this inner exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">Forbidden</message>
</error>
```

whats the problem??

Comment: Where do you host your service? Do you have any kind authentication mechanism enabled there?

Comment: See this blog for hints: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx Also, what is the request you're sending? Did you allow such operation on the given entity set or service operation in your InitializeService?

Comment: Firs of all set config.UseVerboseErrors = true; in the InitializeService method - this should help :)